# forecast::accuracy does not give the same result on the same white-noise model coming from forecast::Arima and forecast::auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I have a time serie object and I'm fitting an arima using forecast::auto.arima() function. As a result, auto.arima find a white-noise model, with every orders equals to 0.
The thing is, when I fit a white-noise model using forecast::Arima() and forcing every order equals to 0 I find exactly the same result -as I was expecting- but when I compute some indicators using forecast::accuracy() function, I find different values for those indicators.

Here's the results I have for both white noise model :
As you can see, the two models are exactly the same :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWnpr.png)

The fitted values are the same too, except that for the white noise coming from the Arima function, it starts with 116 NAs values, which is what I expected because that's how my datas starts. But I don't see how it could impact the accuracy of my models since those models won't predict anything for NA values. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tp68.png)

The x values are exactly the same too :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHqdb.png)

But when I compute indicators using the forecast::accuracy function I get those results :
Results are differents between those two identical models when you look at the indicators MPE, MAPE and MASE. Those indicators are computed on the training set. : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA7Jk.png)

I really don't understand where those differences are coming from and which one of the accuracy result I should consider as reliable, so any help would be welcome.

EDIT : the differences were due to the presence of the NAs values at the beginning of the time serie. When I force my time serie to start from the first non-NA value, here's the result for both of the arima model :
The MPE, MASE and MAPE are very different from one previously computed on the auto.arima model and slighly different from the one previously computed on the Arima model.

So I now have another question : where does thoses differences comes from ? And can I trust those new accuracy metrics ?